# How to Isolate a C# Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting an error in a DLL created with C# in Visual Studio 2013.
Everything is working, except for an intermittent error.  It happens after some time, so it's difficult to isolate exactly where it's coming from.

The message says:

```
Unhandled exception has occurred in a component in your application.
Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
```

It sounds like it should not be hard to correct once the problem code is identified, but there is enough code that it's difficult.
I get the following stack trace which to me isn't too helpful since it doesn't reference any of my application-level code:

```
System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
```

What can I do to get more details about where the problem happens?
I also tried adding a method to capture unhandled exceptions similar to what's mentioned here: [How to "catch" unhandled Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937863/how-to-catch-unhandled-exceptions), but the captured error seems to be identical information.

Comment: is this crashing your app? if its occurring in code you cannot modify or catch you are going to have problems fixing it properly. you can however add a config setting to stop your application crashing on unhandled exceptions (not recommended)

Comment: Is there an `InnerException`?

Comment: It 'crashes' the app in debug mode.  I haven't tried running it without debug.

Comment: The InnerException is null

Comment: There used to be a switch in Visual Studio settings you could use to make the application break in debugger when an exception is thrown. So, if you have the sources of the guilty code, using that will allow you to find the problematic section quickly.

Comment: @user2225104 you referring to the menu `Debug -> Exceptions` and ticking `Thrown` under `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` ?  
@GeorgeHernando you should ensure this is ticked and also in `Debug->Options` *untick* 'Just my code' (temporarily) and then try and recreate your error

Comment: Cannot tell for sure. Just installed VS Community version today. All those settings dialogs do not look as I remember them from back in the day when I used that in another version of Visual Studio.